# Integrate popup bar with Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css

I am using bootstrap 5 and I am trying to integrate a component call `bizzbar`.

Find below my example code:

```js
/*
Bizz Bar
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("open").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
    $("open").slideUp()
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
  $("close").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").slideUp();
    $("open").slideDown()
  })
});
```

```css
/**
 * Hellobar
 */

#bizzbar {
  background: #eb593c;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

#bizzbar button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.854em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 10px 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: initial
}

#bizzbar button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #444
}

#bizzbar button:active {
  top: 1px
}

close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -247px;
  position: absolute
}

close:hover {
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -228px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 19px
}

open {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  background-image: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png);
  background-position: 0px -8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 80px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #eb593c;
  display: none
}

open:hover {
  background-color: #ff5a3d;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
                    <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
                </svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Categoriy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Industries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="text-end">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container pt-3">
  <!--
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Insider</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Apple</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    -->

  <div id='bizzbar'>
    <p class='bizztext'>Drive more attention to your most important website content with Bizz Bar. <button class='bizzbutton'>Click me</button></p>
    <close></close>
  </div>
  <open></open>

  <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">
    Content

  </div>

</main>
<!-- /.container -->
<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Build by Test.com</p>
    <p class="mb-0">You have any questions? <a href="/">Do not hesitate to contact us!</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Currently my hellobar is overlaying my header.

[image]

Any suggestions how to dynamically push my header below the hellobar and if I remove it the header goes up again?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `margin-top` with the same value like the height of the bizzbar (`30px`) when you open the bizzbar and remove it when you close the bizzbar. But this is bad practice because you have to change the script when you change the CSS.

**Working example:** (*i added a `transition` to the header so that it doesn't "jump" when the `margin` is applied*)

```js
/*
Bizz Bar
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
  $('header').css('margin-top', '30px');
  
  $("open").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
    $("open").slideUp();
    $('header').css('margin-top', '30px');
  });
  
  $("close").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").slideUp();
    $("open").slideDown();
    $('header').css('margin-top', '0px');
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  transition: margin .8s;
}

/**
 * Hellobar
 */

#bizzbar {
  background: #eb593c;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

#bizzbar button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.854em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 10px 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: initial
}

#bizzbar button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #444
}

#bizzbar button:active {
  top: 1px
}

close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -247px;
  position: absolute
}

close:hover {
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -228px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 19px
}

open {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  background-image: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png);
  background-position: 0px -8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 80px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #eb593c;
  display: none
}

open:hover {
  background-color: #ff5a3d;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
                    <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
                </svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Categoriy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Industries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="text-end">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container pt-3">
  <!--
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Insider</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Apple</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    -->

  <div id='bizzbar'>
    <p class='bizztext'>Drive more attention to your most important website content with Bizz Bar. <button class='bizzbutton'>Click me</button></p>
    <close></close>
  </div>
  <open></open>

  <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">
    Content

  </div>

</main>
<!-- /.container -->
<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Build by Test.com</p>
    <p class="mb-0">You have any questions? <a href="/">Do not hesitate to contact us!</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

---

A better way would be to check/get the height with the script. Unfortunately the `outerHeight()` only gives the correct result when you close the bizzbar:

```js
/*
Bizz Bar
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
  console.log($('#bizzbar').outerHeight());
  
  $("open").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
    $("open").slideUp();
    
    console.log($('#bizzbar').outerHeight());
  });
  
  $("close").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").slideUp();
    $("open").slideDown();
    
    console.log($('#bizzbar').outerHeight());
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  transition: margin .8s;
}

/**
 * Hellobar
 */

#bizzbar {
  background: #eb593c;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

#bizzbar button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.854em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 10px 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: initial
}

#bizzbar button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #444
}

#bizzbar button:active {
  top: 1px
}

close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -247px;
  position: absolute
}

close:hover {
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -228px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 19px
}

open {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  background-image: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png);
  background-position: 0px -8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 80px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #eb593c;
  display: none
}

open:hover {
  background-color: #ff5a3d;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
                    <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
                </svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Categoriy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Industries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="text-end">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container pt-3">
  <!--
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Insider</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Apple</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    -->

  <div id='bizzbar'>
    <p class='bizztext'>Drive more attention to your most important website content with Bizz Bar. <button class='bizzbutton'>Click me</button></p>
    <close></close>
  </div>
  <open></open>

  <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">
    Content

  </div>

</main>
<!-- /.container -->
<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Build by Test.com</p>
    <p class="mb-0">You have any questions? <a href="/">Do not hesitate to contact us!</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Therefor you have to get `padding` and `border` too and calculate the height:

```js
let bb_height = $('#bizzbar').height();
const bb_padding = parseInt($('#bizzbar').css('padding'));
const bb_border = parseInt($('#bizzbar').css('border-bottom-width'));
  
bb_height += (2 * bb_padding) + bb_border;
```

**Working example:**

```js
/*
Bizz Bar
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  let bb_height = $('#bizzbar').height();
  const bb_padding = parseInt($('#bizzbar').css('padding'));
  const bb_border = parseInt($('#bizzbar').css('border-bottom-width'));
  
  bb_height += (2 * bb_padding) + bb_border;

  $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
  $('header').css('margin-top', bb_height + 'px');
  
  $("open").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").effect("bounce", "slow");
    $("open").slideUp();
    $('header').css('margin-top', bb_height + 'px');
  });
  
  $("close").click(function() {
    $("#bizzbar").slideUp();
    $("open").slideDown();
    $('header').css('margin-top', '0px');
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  transition: margin .8s;
}

/**
 * Hellobar
 */

#bizzbar {
  background: #eb593c;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

#bizzbar button {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.278431) 1px 1px 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.854em;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 10px 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: initial
}

#bizzbar button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #444
}

#bizzbar button:active {
  top: 1px
}

close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  bottom: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -247px;
  position: absolute
}

close:hover {
  background: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png) no-repeat 0px -228px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 19px
}

open {
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  background-image: url(https://hb-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/system/modules/hellobar/lib/sprite-8bit.png);
  background-position: 0px -8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34902) 0px 0px 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 80px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: -50px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #eb593c;
  display: none
}

open:hover {
  background-color: #ff5a3d;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32">
                    <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
                </svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Categoriy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Industries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="text-end">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container pt-3">
  <!--
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Insider</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Apple</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    -->

  <div id='bizzbar'>
    <p class='bizztext'>Drive more attention to your most important website content with Bizz Bar. <button class='bizzbutton'>Click me</button></p>
    <close></close>
  </div>
  <open></open>

  <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">
    Content

  </div>

</main>
<!-- /.container -->
<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mb-1">Build by Test.com</p>
    <p class="mb-0">You have any questions? <a href="/">Do not hesitate to contact us!</a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```